# Why can't Ruby find a method declared right above?

Tags: ruby

I have a simple file called `helper.rb` that looks like this:

```
module MyHelper
  def initialize_helper
    puts "Initialized"
  end

  initialize_helper()
end
```

And another simple file like this:

```
require_relative 'helper.rb'
include MyHelper
puts "Done"
```

But when I run this second file, it results in this error:

```
helper.rb:6:in `<module:MyHelper>': undefined method `initialize_helper' for MyHelper:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Why can't Ruby find this `initializeHelper` method defined directly above where I'm calling it???

Comment: `module MyHelper; def initialize_helper; puts "Initialized": end; end`. We see this defines an instance method: `MyHelper.instance_methods(false) #=> [:initialize_helper]`. `initialize_helper()` is invoked when the module is being parsed, when `self #=> MyHelper`, so it is looking for a module method named `initialized` and finds none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
def self.initialize_helper
  puts "Initialized"
end
```

Without the `self.`, you're declaring an instance method intended to be called on objects, not the module itself. So, for instance, your original code is intended to be used like

```
module MyHelper
  def initialize_helper
    puts "Initialized"
  end
end
class Foo
  include MyHelper
end
Foo.new.initialize_helper
```

But if you want to call it *on* the module, you need to have `self.` in front of it to make it a method on the module itself.

Comment: Thanks.  This is very confusing because modules can't even be instantiated, right?

Comment: @Dasmowenator, but modules provide instance methods for classes they included in.

Comment: Think of it like defining an instance method on an abstract class in Java. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be used in children.

Comment: `def initialize_helper ... end; module_function :initialize_helper` would be a more correct way of doing this. It will make `MyHelper.initialize_helper` work and `Foo.new.initialize_helper` becomes private.